# browser.pages() does not switch to newly opened tab in puppeteer

Tags: tabs, puppeteer

I am trying to open a new tab and scrape information from the new tab using puppeteer. I am doing

```
pages = browser.pages();
new_tab = pages[pages.length - 1] 
new_tab.screenshot({path: "sample.png"});
```

to switch to the new tab and take a screenshot. However, puppeteer doesn't switch to the new tab and takes a screenshot of the old tab instead. After some debugging I realized that the new tab isn't added to pages for some reason. Specifically, I used pages.length() which returned 2, pages[0] manipulates the pre-existing blank page and pages[1] = pages[pages.length()-1] manipulates the previous page.How do I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Please, provide more context: how the new page is opened before you try to get it.

Comment: I was actually able to fix the issue, thanks for the quick response